# Questions about stack STL in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stack

So I'm trying to understand what the stack STL allows you to do. I know that you start by first including the stack and then creating an object like this:

```
#include<stack>
stack<int> calcStack;
```

But what I want to understand is that now that I have created a stack how can I add number to it and then read them out. From a video I saw someone simply do this:

```
calcStack.push(1); //Adding the number one to the top of the stack
calcStack.top();   //Reading the number at the top of the stack
calcStack.pop();   //Removing the number at the top of the stack

cout << calcstack.top << endl; //This should print out one
```

Does that mean that I can just use the function `.push() .top() .pop()` without having to define them in a .cpp file? Also should I be creating my stack in the header file, the implementation file or the file with the main class?

This is my first time using stacks and I just started working with C++ so any guidance would be appreciated!!!

Comment: `stack<int>` is a type like any other one in C++. It has no special rules. Do what you do with other types.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean. I was asking if including the stack STD means I can use push and pop without having to define them.

Comment: you mean `top()` rather than `top` in that last line.

Comment: "the stack STL" "the stack STD" no no no it's the standard container called `std::stack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to define any of the functions for the stack. It is part of the **standard library**. Which means the library itself has defined them for you.

All you need to worry about is:

1. including the correct header
2. linking to the correct library (the standard library is linked in automatically when you compile with g++ (instead of gcc). If you are using MSVC, then it too will automatically link in the standard library.

Frankly, the only reason when I mentioned point #2 here is because with other libraries this is something that you will need to do. And is a common source of "linker errors".